# How to erase from an array only one element also if duplicated with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

This is my problem: if I try to erase the last element that I pushed with the relative button everything works, but if I try to erase the first (or at least not the last one), all the elements in the array are erased.

To avoid this I used $.inArray to check if the element is in the Array and to erase only the element in that index, but it doesn't help.

What I want is to be able to erase the element I want and only the one that I select.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var array = [];

  $('.add').click(function(e) {
    var $thisEvent = $(e.currentTarget).closest('.event');
    var i = $thisEvent.find('.i').text();
    array.push(i);
    console.log(i +' added, Array is now ' + array);  
    $thisEvent.append('<button class="remove">' + i + '</button>');
    
    var $total = 0;
    for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
       $total += array[y] << 0;
    }
    
    $('.total').html('The sum of the elements in the array is ' + $total);
    
    $('.remove').click(function() {
      if ($.inArray(i, array) !== -1) {
        array.splice($.inArray(i, array), 1);
        console.log(i + ' removed, Array is now ' + array);
      } else {
        console.log('There is no ' + i + ' to remove from the array!');
      }
      $(this).remove();
      
      var $total = 0;
      for (var y = 0; y < array.length; y++) {
       $total += array[y] << 0;
      }
      
      $('.total').html('The sum of the elements in the array is ' + $total);
    }); 
  });    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="event">
  <span class="i" style="margin-right: 5px;">1</span><button class="add">Add to Array</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="event">
  <span class="i" style="margin-right: 5px;">2</span><button class="add">Add to Array</button>
</div>
<br />
<div class="event">
  <span class="i" style="margin-right: 5px;">3</span><button class="add">Add to Array</button>
</div>
<p class="total"></p>
```

Comment: Big problem is `$('.remove').click..`. This adds event listener to ***all*** `$('.remove')` ... not just the one that was created inside `add`

Comment: How can I solve it? If I put the `$('.remove').click..`outside the `add` it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing

```
$thisEvent.append('<button class="remove">' + i + '</button>');
```

To

```
var $remove = $('<button class="remove">' + i + '</button>');
$thisEvent.append($remove);
```

Then change

```
$('.remove').click(function() {
```

To

```
$remove.click(function() {
```

This way you aren't adding a new click event listener to all the other remove buttons every time a new one is added